# How do I record inputs within a for loop?

Tags: c++

I'm attempting to make a program that asks for a class size that will define how many times the program asks for a test score.
Once it gets this it asks for the test score using a for loop until it reaches the class size.
What I want to do is record each score so that it can be announced at the end but I'm not sure how to record each seperate input within the code I am using. I want it to run something like:

> Enter Score: 95
>     Enter Score: 25
>     Original Scores: 95,25

if the user entered the class size of 2. How do I do this? Maybe with an array but I dont know how to encorporate this?

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;


int main()
{
    int size;
    double score;
    cout << "Enter class size <1-20> \n";
    cin >> size;
    for (int i = 0; 0 <= size; i++) {
        cout << "Enter Score \n";
        cin >> score;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it just using a `double` array. Here is the code snippet.

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;


int main()
{
    int size;
    double score[20]; // as size must me less than or equal 20
    cout << "Enter class size <1-20> \n";
    cin >> size;
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        cout << "Enter Score \n";
        cin >> score[i];
    }
    cout<<"Original Scores: "; 

    // Now iterate through all scores.
    for(int i=0;i<size; i++){
       if(i){
           cout<<",";
       }
       cout<<score[i]
    }
    return 0;
}
```

**Note**: score size (20) is not checked.

Comment: `if(i !=0 ){` -> `if(i){`, pretty please, with sugar on top?

Answer (score 5):

Just before the `for` loop, instantiate a `std::vector<double> scores(size);`. That is what you will use to record all the scores. (Write `#include <vector>` to bring in this functionality.)

Then fix the typos in your loop `for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {`.

Then adjust the `cin` to `cin >> scores[i];`. (Isn't the C++ standard library clever?! Don't try to understand the mechanics behind that just yet - just accept the notation as plausible).

You can then *iterate* through that `std::vector` to output the scores. Lots of questions on this site to show you how to do that.

(Eventually you'll use a `std::size_t` as the type for the vector index rather than an `int`.)

Answer (score 0):

It's possible to write even more compact code for reading values using range-for:

```
size_t sz;
std::cin >> sz;
std::vector<double> input(sz);
for(auto& el : input)
    std::cin >> el;
```